# Distinct linear combinations of a particular kind of n polynomials of degree t(<n) over a finite field of size bigger than and independent of n.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Suppose, $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ are distinct points in a finite field $\mathcal{F}$ whose size is bigger than and independent of $n$. Also, $P_0(x), P_1(x),\ldots, P_n(x)$ are randomly chosen $t$ $(<n)$ degree polynomials over $\mathcal{F}$. Does it necessarily imply that the cardinality of the set $\mathcal{T}$ $=$ $\{P_0(x) + a_iP_1(x) + {a_i}^2P_2(x) + \cdots + {a_i}^nP_n(x) \mid i = 1,2,\dots, n \}$ is $n$?

Intuitively, I think the cardinality is not, in general, $n$, given the fact that the polynomials are randomly chosen but neither I could prove the statement nor find a counterexample.

Please, consider the finite field to be of **prime characteristic**. This eventually leads to the fact that it is bit difficult to provide a specific example but it MAY be possible to provide a 'hunch' or intuition about the counterexample. That much will do.

Also, I would like to request to consider $n$ to be at least more than 100.

(I found some questions in the forum addressing the nature of roots or linear combinations of polynomials over a finite field but none of them answers this.)

Comment: Pick $n = 2, \mathcal{F} = \mathbb{F}_5, a_1 = 2, a_2 = 4, P_0 = 2x, P_1 = 3x, P_2 = 2x$, then $P_0 + a_1 P_1 + a_1^2 P_2 = x = P_0 + a_2 P_1 + a_2^2 P_2$. So $|\mathcal{T}| = 1 < n$, which is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Vong for the counterexample. However, the way I had placed this question was incomplete, now I understand. What I am specifically looking for is a technique or rather insight about how one can counter-exemplify the statement of the question. Please, consider the finite field of prime characteristic. This eventually leads to the fact that it is bit difficult to provide a specific example but it MAY be possible to provide a 'hunch' or intuition about the counterexample. That much will do.

Sorry for the confusion. I am editing the question accordingly.